# Laplace equation (polar coordinates) with non-homogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've been trying to solve this problem with separation of variables where T is a function of r and z

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r})+\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial z^2}=0$$

$$\left.-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right\rvert_{r=R}=h[T(R,z)-T_{\infty}]$$

$$\left.-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}\right\rvert_{z=H}+h[T(r,H)-T_{\infty}]=q_s$$

$$T(r,0)=T_0$$

$$\left.-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right\rvert_{x=0}=0$$

$where \ T_0 \ ,T_{\infty} \ and \ q_s \ are \ constants$

I did a change of variable $\theta(r,z) = T(r,z)-T_{\infty}$ which resulted in

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r})+\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial z^2}=0$$

$$\left.-k\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r}\right\rvert_{r=R}=h\theta$$

$$\left.-k\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}\right\rvert_{z=H}+h\theta=q_s$$

$$\theta(r,0)=\theta_0$$

$$\left.-k\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r}\right\rvert_{x=0}=0$$

I've been trying to solve it but the non-homogeneous BC, the one that equals to $q_s$ has been giving me problems. If I use $\theta (r,z)=G(r)M(z)$ I get
$$G(r)=C_1J_0(\lambda r)$$ and $$M(z)=C_3\cosh(\lambda z)+C_4\sinh(\lambda z)$$

To find $C_3$ and $C_4$ becomes a problem, if $q_s$ wasn't there I could express $C_3$ in terms of $\lambda , C_4$ and other functions. I've solved problems where there is a similar condition as the one with $q_s$ but T is a function of x and time $T(x,t)$ and I can apply something called "transient temperature" which is more or less a change of variable that looks like $T(x,t)=u(x,t)+v(x)$. Here I'm just stuck.

In case it is important, the equation and boundary conditions come from a two dimensional heat flow problem, where a cylinder with a radius R and a height H gets applied a uniform heat flux $q_s$ on the top. At the same time the cylinder undergoes convection and one of its faces is in contact with a surface at $T_0$, i.e. the cylinder has one of its "circular faces" resting against a surface while all the uncovered faces experience convection, and the other uncovered "circular face" has a uniform heat flux applied to it.

I have to find the temperature distribution i.e. $\theta (r,z)$

Hope I'm making myself clear, I'm just trying to get help.

Comment: "the other uncovered 'circular face' has a uniform heat flux applied to it" - do you mean uniform *temperature*, as is suggested by the B.C. $T (r, 0) = T_0$ listed in your original system?

Comment: no, such temperature "value" is unkown and it has to be expressed on terms of an energy balance, that is heat flux = heat convection + heat conduction, that is the BC with qs. $T_0$ is for " the cylinder has one of its "circular faces" resting against a surface" such surface is at $T_0$

Comment: Right, ok; I think I just misread that last paragraph. So the bottom face is at constant temperature $T_0$ and the upper face has a constant heat flux $q_S''$. But I don't think you should consider convection when writing the energy balance for the upper face. Take an infinitessimally thin slice $A \times dz$; then there is no convection through the rounded face.

Comment: @Gonçalo That unfortunately won't work because of the convective BC.

Comment: @K.Jiang hmm I didn't quite get why to use the infinitessimally thin slice to to disregard the convection. My reasoning here is when the heat flux is applied the top surface would heat up and part of it would transform into heat conduction, but since h is given in the problem it makes me think that this is a general case, I mean h may be really big so the convection can be ignored or it may be really small, the case is i don't know so i should work with the general case not ignoring convection

Comment: What I mean is that the convection term should not show up in the $\hat{z} = 1$ BC because the given heat flux $q_S''$ is in the axial direction (rather than the radial direction). Convection itself is obviously not ignored since it shows up in the radial condition at $\hat{r} = 1$.

Comment: @Gonçalo ignoring if writing $\theta (r,z)=u(r,z)+v(z)$ might work, I have a question, such trick can be done?, I mean, is it valid? Because I've read that the transient temperature is a experimental fact, when t approaches infinity the temperature distribution is given by $v(x)$ because $u(x,t)$ approaches zero

Comment: @K.Jiang okayy, another thing is that I asked my proffesor about it and he told us not to ignore convection on the top surface. I know it would be simpler if I could neglect convection at the top surface and only take it on the sides

Comment: Ah, so the top face is both uncovered *and* there's an additional fixed heat flux in addition to the convection?

Comment: @Gonçalo I've been trying your approach but I'm still getting stuck, it is not clear how $v(r,z)$ should look like, since in this case interpolation won't work I'm pretty clueless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea is good. Let's start with a statement of the problem.

Solve

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{r} \partial_r (r \partial_r T) + \partial_{z z} T = 0 & \text{subject to} \\
T (r, z = 0) = T_0 \\
-k \frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \big|_{z = H} = q_S'' + h (T (r, H) - T_\infty) \\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \big|_{r = 0} = 0 \\
-k \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \big|_{r = R} = h (T (R, z) - T_\infty)
\end{cases}$$

Like you've done, the first step is to define a nondimensional temperature difference $\Theta = \frac{T - T_\infty}{T_0 - T_\infty}$ which helps to make the convection condition homogeneous. While we're at it, let's define non-dimensional variables $\hat{r} = \frac{r}{R} \in [0, 1]$, $\hat{z} = \frac{z}{H} \in [0, 1]$, $\hat{q}_S'' = \frac{q_S'' H}{k (T_0 - T_\infty)}$, ${\rm Bi} = \frac{h R}{k}$, and $\Pi = \frac{H}{R}$. Our system becomes

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\hat{r}} \partial_{\hat{r}} (\hat{r} \partial_{\hat{r}} \Theta) + \frac{1}{\Pi^2} \partial_{\hat{z} \hat{z}} \Theta = 0 & \text{subject to} \\
\Theta (\hat{r}, \hat{z} = 0) = 1  \\
\frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial \hat{z}} \big|_{\hat{z} = 1} = -(\hat{q}_S'' + \Pi {\rm Bi} \Theta (\hat{r}, \hat{z} = 1)) \\
\frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial \hat{r}} \big|_{\hat{r} = 0} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial \hat{r}} \big|_{\hat{r} = 1} = -{\rm Bi} \Theta (\hat{r} = 1, \hat{z})
\end{cases}$$

The boundary conditions in $\hat{r}$ here are homogeneous. Therefore, we may consider a solution by separation of variables:

$$\Theta = \sum_n g_n (\hat{z}) J_0 (\lambda_n \hat{r})$$

where $J_0$ are Bessel functions of the first kind. Because we know that $\frac{d }{d x} J_0 (x) = -J_1 (x)$, the eigenvalues satisfy

$$\lambda_n \frac{J_1 (\lambda_n)}{J_0 (\lambda_n)} = {\rm Bi}$$

Substituting this solution into the homogeneous governing equation, we find that for each mode $n$,

$$\left( -\lambda_n^2 g_n + \frac{1}{\Pi^2} g_n'' \right) J_0 (\lambda_n \hat{r}) = 0$$

which means that

$$g_n'' - (\lambda_n \Pi)^2 g_n = 0 \implies g_n = C_{1, n} \cosh (\lambda_n \Pi \hat{z}) + C_{2, n} \sinh (\lambda_n \Pi \hat{z})$$

where $C_{1, n}, C_{2, n}$ are unknown constants determined by the remaining boundary conditions in $\hat{z}$. Decomposing into the Bessel basis, we have that constant functions have coefficients

$$\langle J_0 (\lambda_n \hat{r}) | 1 \rangle = \frac{2}{\lambda_n} \frac{J_1 (\lambda_n)}{J_0^2 (\lambda_n) + J_1^2 (\lambda_n)}$$

Therefore, the boundary condition at $\hat{z} = 0$ gives

$$C_{1, n} = 2 \left( \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \right) \left( \frac{J_1 (\lambda_n)}{J_0^2 (\lambda_n) + J_1^2 (\lambda_n)} \right)$$

The boundary condition at $\hat{z} = 1$ can be rewritten as $\frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial \hat{z}} \big|_{\hat{z} = 1} + \Pi {\rm Bi} \Theta (\hat{r}, \hat{z} = 1) = -\hat{q}_S''$.

$$C_{1, n} (\lambda_n \Pi \sinh (\lambda_n \Pi) + \Pi {\rm Bi} \cosh (\lambda_n \Pi)) + C_{2, n} (\lambda_n \Pi \cosh (\lambda_n \Pi) + \Pi {\rm Bi} \sinh (\lambda_n \Pi)) = -\frac{2 \hat{q}_S''}{\lambda_n} \frac{J_1 (\lambda_n)}{J_0^2 (\lambda_n) + J_1^2 (\lambda_n)}$$

$$\implies C_{2, n} = -2 \left( \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \right) \left( \frac{\hat{q}_S'' + \lambda_n \Pi \sinh (\lambda_n \Pi) + \Pi {\rm Bi} \cosh (\lambda_n \Pi)}{\lambda_n \Pi \cosh (\lambda_n \Pi) + \Pi {\rm Bi} \sinh (\lambda_n \Pi)} \right) \left( \frac{J_1 (\lambda_n)}{J_0^2 (\lambda_n) + J_1^2 (\lambda_n)} \right)$$

The solutions above unfortunately aren't very numerically stable, but they do work while keeping a moderate number of modes. I plot below the solution for ${\rm Bi} = 1.0$, $\Pi = 1.0$, and $\hat{q}_S'' = -3.0$ (prescribed heat flux *heats* the system):

[image: Temperature profiles for heating case]

and for ${\rm Bi} = 1.0$, $\Pi = 1.0$, and $\hat{q}_S'' = 3.0$ (prescribed heat flux *cools* the system):

[image: Temperature profiles for cooling case]

Comment: Sorry if I sound too clueless, but the step where you wrote "Decomposing into the Bessel basis, we have that constant functions have coefficients" I don't know what that means and neither the brackets you used. Are there any resources that you know of so I can understand this better?

Comment: @jackgatz Are you familiar with Fourier series? It is essentially the same idea here, except instead of complex exponentials, here we have Bessel functions. The bracket denotes an inner product under an appropriate weighting; the coefficients of the series are determined by projecting a function onto the basis functions.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly, what you are essentially doing is using orthogonality as in Fourier series, to express other functions with bessel functions? In the step with the inner product, you are trying to express a function, in this case taking 1 as the "function", in bessel functions And that this would work for any constant term, not necessarily 1?

Comment: That's correct. The only real difference with Fourier series is that the inner product for the Bessel basis is defined by $\langle f | g \rangle \equiv \int_{[0, 1]} x f (x) g (x) d x$ (rather than the familiar $\int_{[0, 1]} f (x) g (x) d x$ for the Fourier basis). Yes, "$1$" is meant to represent the constant function $g (x) = 1$. If you have a constant function $g (x) = k$, then by linearity we of course have that $\langle f | k \rangle = k \langle f | 1 \rangle$.